# How to solve [WDS] Disconnected! error in Angular 7 and Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ssl-certificate

When working with latest Angular (7) and ionic (4) I got the error

`[WDS] Disconnected!`

every time I run my app via

`ionic serve --consolelogs --no-open --browser='firefox developer edition' --source-map`

in the latest firefox developer edition. I tested other brothers too and it appears in the most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was not simple, I have read many stack questions and their answers and also searched the web a few times, without a good solution until I have read this issue on GitHub:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4839

So this error is a simple SSL error, as I understood the browser could not verify the certificate from which webpack dev server has send to the browser.

**The Solution**

When using ionic (4) you can simply type `ionic ssl generate` in the root of your project and then go to your browser settings:

- Firefox (65.0b8): Settings -> Safety -> Scroll down to "Certificates"
  -> Click on "Show certificates" -> Click on "Import" -> Choose the generated `cert.pem` from your project -> restart (CMD+Q) your
  browser
- Chrome on macOS (77): install the cert in Keychain and allow all
- Others: must be similiar to firefox

If you just use Angular with Webpack you can generate a certificate by using this script: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4839#issuecomment-314608490 and follow this https://brianflove.com/2016/10/22/angular-cli-using-https/

Comment: I use Angular with Webpack, sometimes error messages continue to occur, sometimes there are no errors...

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Chrome you can try allowing invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost:

```
chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

IE 11 was giving me that error 
to get rid of that, I've added this parameter :

```
disableHostCheck: true
```

to my backend's conf.js file